# Salesforce API: Department field on Contact

Tags: soql, rest-api, api, contact

I'm performing queries on the `Contact` object in Salesforce via the API, and I want to access the `Department` field.  I'm using a query like this:

```
SELECT Department FROM Contact WHERE Id='1234'
```

Which fails with the error:

```
No such column 'Department' on entity 'Contact'.
```

When viewing the `Contact` object via the web interface, `Department` is listed as a standard field.  I know Salesforce uses different names in the API than the web UI, so I used SoqlXplorer to search for a "real" field name.  But I can't find anything that looks like a department.

Anyone know the correct field name?  Thanks.

Comment: Are you a sys admin, if not did you check the field level security for your profile on the field department, prolly its hidden for you?

Comment: Thanks, rao.  It was disabled for all profiles.  A previous admin must have set it up that way out my company.  Appreciate it!

Comment: most welcome :) glad that I could help

Comment: Can you, RobotNerd, or rao post this as the answer, then accept it, so this question shows as 'answered'? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you have access to the field. If you are not a sys admin/ the Field level setting for the description field is not visible for the user's profile, you would end up having no such column error.